# Are specific code signing identities needed to distribute ios app?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, identity

I am extremely confused about the "code signing" section of the Project's Build Settings in Xcode. If I am trying to upload my app to the app store, are there specific code signing identities needed or is "iOS Developer" & "iOS Distributor" all right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code signing build setting is irrelevant for deploying to the app store.

When you deploy the app (by building an archive, and then clicking "distribute" on the archive in the organiser) it will ask you to select a certificate to sign the app with.

At that stage it will only let you sign with the correct one, and that signature will override whatever was chosen in build settings.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Developer and iOS Distributor are perfectly fine.